# What are other uses for Vegemite or Marmite besides as a spread?

Tags: culinary-uses, yeast

My Australian friend introduced toast with butter and vegemite to me.  Recently I saw an episode of "Chopped" on the food network and one of the ingredients in the basket was Marmite.  One of the chefs used it to flavor ground beef to make a burger or meatloaf.

I want to know what have you guys used Vegemite or Marmite for...other than as a spread.  :)

Comment: good question; please mark Community Wiki since it is a list request

Comment: @Michael: Your vigilance is appreciated; in the future, please use the "Flag for moderator attention" link, as we can convert the entire thread including answers (and it doesn't require the author to do anything extra).  Thanks!

Comment: Having tasted both, is answering "an industrial lubricant" reasonable? :)

Answer (score 13):

One good use for it is to amp up the flavor of vegetarian gravy. If you are making say biscuits and gravy, a tablespoon of marmite will add some umami without tasting like soy sauce. Same for a vegetarian pot pie or stew.

Comment: I came here basically to say this. I use it any time I need some beef-stockesque base.

Answer (score 4):

It can be used in a similar way to Worcestershire sauce; to add a deeper richer flavour (and salt) so goes well in cheese sandwiches for instance.

The only time you'll see it in a recipe book is as "Yeast Extract" in, for instance, french onion soup.

Answer (score 2):

I use a teaspoonful (marmite - not the vegemite imposter) it in a cheese sauce  to beef it up a bit.

Comment: Flame War!             http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/6867/what-are-other-uses-for-vegemite-or-marmite-besides-as-a-spread/7044#7044

Answer (score 2):

In Scotland we made it into a hot drink, when I was a child.  I still do that when I find a jar to buy.

Comment: I thought Bovril was used for the drink not Marmite?

Answer (score 2):

put some cooked and drained noodles in a bowl, add a generous knob of butter, moisten with warmed cream, and stir in Lea & Perrins Worcester sauce to taste, Marmite to taste, and grated Parmesan to taste.

Answer (score 1):

My [Marmite soup](http://richcooks.blogspot.com/2008/02/marmite-soup.html), with browned butter and canned pumpkin, is easy and delicious. You can see from the commenters that some people have had different results.  If you try it, do let me know how it turns out.

I regularly use Marmite in place of chicken stock, but only when the surrounding flavors are going to be strong enough to mask the distinct yeastiness a bit.  One place it works particularly well is in vegetarian orrecchiette with broccoli rabe.

Comment: When I first tasted Vegemite, I described it as tasting like vegetable bouillon cubes.  :)

Comment: Yup, and Marmite is basically the same thing, but with boiled down autolyzed beer yeast.

Answer (score 1):

It's good in french onion soup.